# Building a dynamic $_POST statement

Tags: php, mysql

ingHey guys.

I am wonder the correct syntax for using a $_POST statement in a while loop.

I have written this.

```
$result_i = $_POST['result_i'];
while ($result_i > 0){
        //Get Post Values
        $driver = $_POST['driver_update_".$result_i."'];
        $BookingID = $_POST['ID_".$result_i."'];
        $Task_No_update = $_POST['Task_No_update_".$result_i."'];

        //SQL 
        $driver_update = mysql_query("UPDATE booking SET driver = '$driver', TaskNo= '$Task_No_update' WHERE BookingID = '$BookingID' " );
}
```

The problem I have is:

```
$_POST['driver_update_".$result_i."'];
```

Is it possible to write $_POSTS statements in this way.

Cheers.

Comment: As an added thought, why not use this instead?  It will create an array inside the POST array, that you can foreach through. Name each element `name="something[]"` then use this to loop through it `foreach ($_POST["something"] as $val)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you cannot interpolate variables in single-quoted strings.

Try concatenation instead

```
$_POST['driver_update_' . $result_i]
```

or use double-quotes and variable enclosures

```
$_POST["driver_update_{$result_i}"]
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

---

Also, that looks like an infinite loop as `$result_i` never changes.

Comment: Cheers Phil Brown! I forgot to add the $result_i--;

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wrap everything in quotes here

```
$driver = $_POST["driver_update_" . $result_i];
$BookingID = $_POST["ID_" . $result_i];
$Task_No_update = $_POST["Task_No_update_" . $result_i];
```

Comment: Cheers Andre. Just got confused with the syntax.